# How do margins work in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

**main_layout.xml**:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CollapsingTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: large text]
[image: small text]

It looks like bounded to the edges *ConstraintLayout* doesn't consider **any** horizontal margins and just horizontally centeres the *TextView*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you have the width of the TextView set to `"wrap_content"`.

To force it to adapt to the constraints you need to use a width of `"0dp"`. This is the functional equivalent of `"match_constraint"` however that is not currently recognized as an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CollapsingTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```